# Converting a cell to matrix in the presence of a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell-array

I am running a LASSO estimation method alongside a for loop.

Here is the code:

```
%Lasso    
data = rand(246,3);        %random data for illistrative purposes
XL1 = lagmatrix(data,1);   %Lags the data matrix by one period
ydata = data;              %Specifies the dependent variable
ydata([1],:)=[];           %Removes the top row due to the lagged X
XL1([1],:)=[];             %Removes the top row of the lagged X with become a NaN from lagmatrix
for ii = 1:3               %For loop to complete LASSO for all industries
    y = ydata(:,ii);           %y is the industry we are trying to forecast
    rng default                % For reproducibility, as the LASSO uses some random numbers
    [B,FitInfo] = lasso([XL1],y,'CV',10,'PredictorNames',{'x1','x2','x3'});
    idxLambdaMinMSE = FitInfo.IndexMinMSE;
    ii
    minMSEModelPredictors = FitInfo.PredictorNames(B(:,idxLambdaMinMSE)~=0)
end
```

The output that the LASSO provides is

```
ii = 1    
minMSEModelPredictors =    
  1×1 cell array    
{'x2'}

ii =  2
minMSEModelPredictors =
  1×5 cell array
{'x1'}    {'x2'}    {'x3'}

ii = 3
minMSEModelPredictors =
  1×2 cell array
{'x2'}    {'x3'}
```

For the purposes of automating this, I need the result to be reported in the following manner,

```
Results = {[2],[1 2 3],[2 3]};
```

I know this is a long shot, but it would be helpful as the above is easy to type out but If I increase the dimensions, this becomes a very difficult task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each output of `minMSEModelPredictors` is a cell array of the form

```
minMSEModelPredictors  = {'x1', 'x2', 'x3'};
```

We can use `strrep` to get rid of the `'x'` (or just don't have an `'x'` in your predictor names to begin with), and `str2double` to convert the cell array to a numeric array.

Then storing the results is trivial...

```
Result = cell(1,3); % Initialise output
for ii = 1:3
    % stuff...
    minMSEModelPredictors = FitInfo.PredictorNames(B(:,idxLambdaMinMSE)~=0);

    Result{ii} = str2double( strrep( minMSEModelPredictors, 'x', '' ) );
end
```